# Create custom date format Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm looking to create a custom date format for Elasticsearch. I have data in formats like:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

Is it possible to create  a single custom date format to accept all 3 forms of the datetimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple formats by separating them with `||` as a separator. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#multiple-date-formats) is the link to the official documentation with an example.